# Why using archive pages at all?

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, archives

I searched through some questions and it was a surprise this never was asked before.

I have a lot of customers who maintain there Wordpress sites that i created for them. I often get the question, why Archive pages are not found in backend menu sites to customize them.

My question is: Is there a disadvantage of not using archives for custom post types? Its quite easy nowadays to disable archive functionality for cpt and showing the posts of the cpt on a single page.

Comment: FWIW, they are editable in modern block themes.

Comment: I'd add that many modern themes altogether make it very easy to modify the archive pages.